# Is there a way to style named parameters in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I think named parameters are good, but I think the downside is they add some visual noise to function calls. I want Visual Studio to color them light gray (the way ReSharper grays out dead code), so that the actual parameter values are emphasized.

Looks somewhat like this now (everything is black):

> **LaunchThings(planes: true, boats:false, rocketship: true, nukes: false);**

I want it to look like this:

> **LaunchThings(** planes: **true**, boats:**false**, rocketship: **true**, nukes: **false);**

Comment: I have noticed that ReSharper does that and I was quite pleased when I first saw that.

Comment: @CharlesPrakashDasari resharper only seems to do this if the name is redundant. If you disable that inspection, the name is not grayed out.

Comment: I'd like to know if you have solved this issue anyhow. Thanks

Comment: @LuisFilipe no, i have not solved it, though I am considering making a resharper plugin to do this (resharper will only gray out the parameters names if they are redundant and will suggest removing them, whereas i want it to gray out all parameter names and not suggest removing them)

Comment: @dan Furthermore, i'd like to change the indentation of named parameters when i put each one in its own line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing currently in Visual Studio that would allow you to do this.  You could create an extension or an add-in to do this as I'm unaware of any extensions/add-ins that already do this.  [DxCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) is a library to extend visual studio "easier".  Maybe that would less the burden of creating an extension like this.